# ES6: filter then map -> is there a way to find the number of elements out of the filter?

Tags: ecmascript-6

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

let a = arr.filter( data => {
   return data > 5;
}).map ( (data,index) => {
   // while in here -- is there away to know that only 3 elements came out of the filter? 
});
```

Yes, I know I can wait for the `a.length` when this is over, but while IN the map -- can I find out how many items made it through the filter?

Comment: Use the third parameter of the `.map` callback - it gives you the array you are iterating over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map method's callback accepts a third argument that gives you the array being mapped, you can use the length property on that.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

let a = arr.filter( data => {
   return data > 5;
}).map ( (data,index,arr) => {
   console.log(arr.length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. just what I needed.